# Save image after being processed in apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, python-imaging-library

I have an Apache Spark application that runs a series of transformations on my image dataset and returns tiles of those images. Everything is going fine with the transformations but nothing happens when I save the images locally.

```
def save_rdd_2_jpeg(rdd, save_dir):
    rdd.foreach(lambda sample_element: save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample_element, save_dir))

def save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample, save_dir):
    slide_num, img_value = sample
    filename = '{slide_num}_{hash}.jpeg'.format(
        slide_num=slide_num, hash=np.random.randint(1e4))
    filepath = os.path.join(save_dir, filename)
    save_jpeg_help(img_value, filepath)


def save_jpeg_help(img_value, filepath):
    print(filepath)
    dir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
    img = Image.fromarray(img_value.astype(np.uint8), 'RGB')
    #img.show()
    img.save(filepath)
```

The filepath that I'm saving my files into is `data/train_256/1_6300.jpeg`. This path should be automatically created with

```
dir = os.path.dirname(filepath)
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
```

If I uncomment the `#img.show()` line, the image opens. I really don't know why it isn't saving. My guess is since the application is running in a different path, something like `/usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/app-20181206041146-0000/0`, I'm not able to save to that local path.

Any idea what's happening and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Spark is behaving correctly as it supposes to be, 
If you want to save to local you have to collect the RDD into Array[Image] and then store each image,

Collect actually brings all the data to the driver node, In that case, this will work,
**Updated**

```
sample_elements = rdd.collect();
for sample_element in sample_elements:
    save_nonlabelled_sample_2_jpeg(sample_element, save_dir);
```

Comment: It does not work. It says that the `list object has not attribute foreach`

Comment: would you be able to give me a little help? I need this to work so bad and I've tried everything

Comment: Actually, I just gave you a hint, RDD.Collect will give you a list of images. then store the images, by loop through the elements, I've updated the code is the answer.